# Slow data processing with Dynamics SDK

Tags: c#, asp.net, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-365

We're working on a ASP.NET MVC Application that is integrated with Dynamics. The project uses the Dynamics SDK to pass data to Dynamics which is either inserted or updated. It really is quite a light touch integration - during the shop checkout process of the website we collate data and pass it off to Dynamics (which is hosted in Dynamics 365). An example of creating a user account in our Dynamics instance can be seen below:

```
        public Guid? CreateProfile(IProfile profile)
    {
        using (var xrm = new XrmServiceContext(_crmConnection))
        {
            var crmProfile = new Contact
            {
                EMailAddress1 = profile.Username,
                FirstName = profile.FirstName,
                LastName = profile.LastName,
            };
            xrm.AddObject(crmProfile);
            xrm.SaveChanges();
            return crmProfile.Id;
        }
    }
```

The xrm.SaveChanges() method can take up to 20 seconds to complete. Using Fiddler we can see that there is no major HTTP overhead causing slow requests to the Dynamics instance, which seems to suggest that the processing of the data by Dynamics once it has received the request is slow.

Does anyone have any pointers/tips on how to speed this up, or why it's taking so long to process? If Dynamics were running on a VM i'd just throw extra resources at it, but of course we dont have control over the infrastructure in this scenario.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks for your time in advance

Kind regards

dotdev

Comment: Any plugins? real time workflows that run on `create` of a contact?

Answer (score 3):

First, do you have any plugins or real-time workflows executing? If so, disable them and confirm that you are still having this performance problem (i.e., the problem is native CRM and nothing to do with your configuration or customization.)

Are you create a new `_crmConnection` object each time? If so, are you caching the authorization token. The most likely cause here would be the security handshake with ADFS. 20 seconds would still be slow. I've seen that take as long as 5 seconds but the average is much lower (2 or so seconds, in my experience.)

I built the following as a quick performance test of creating a `Contact` entity. I pointed it at a Dynamics 365 trial. You can run this LINQPad by creating an `IOrganizationService` object as `conn`. This is probably a good place to start narrowing down the issue.

```
// See http://nicknow.net/linqpad-dynamics-crm-sdk/ for a method to create IOrganizationService in LINQPad
IOrganizationService conn = MyExtensions.GetCRMService("Valid CRM Connection String Goes Here");

conn.Execute(new WhoAmIRequest());

var times = new List<long>();

for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++)
{
    var crmProfile = new Entity("contact");

    crmProfile["emailaddress1"] = "test@demo.com.local";
    crmProfile["firstname"] = "test";
    crmProfile["lastname"] = $"test {i}";

    var sw = new Stopwatch();

    sw.Start();
    conn.Create(crmProfile);
    sw.Stop();

    times.Add(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    }

Console.WriteLine($"Total Transactions: {times.Count()} / Average Time: {times.Average()} ms / Max Time: {times.Max()} ms / Min Time: {times.Min()} ms");
```

I got the following results:

**Total Transactions: 25 / Average Time: 268.2 ms / Max Time: 714 ms / Min Time: 207 ms**

Here is an image of it running via Fiddler. You can see the initial security authorization and then 26 calls to the Organization.svc endpoint. There is one `WhoAmIRequest` and then 25 `Create` calls.

[image: Fiddler of Performance Test]

Comment: Hi Nick, thanks so much for your detailed response. It'll be Thursday before I can try the code out, but i'll come back to you to let you know how i get on rest assured. Again, many thanks.

Comment: Hi Nick - thanks again for your detailed response. I have just gotten round to tetsing your quick testbed and my results look like:
Total Transactions: 25 / Average Time: 3290.08 ms / Max Time: 5526 ms / Min Time: 2551 ms

I can only see about 3 workflows attached to the Contact entity. Would you advise deactivating them and see what results i get then??

Comment: Well now I'm curious where you are getting 20 seconds of transaction time. If your worst case here was 5 seconds (doing, essentially, the same transaction.) You can certainly try deactivating any real-time workflows and/or plugins to determine their impact. I would also go to https://ORGNAMEURL/tools/diagnostics/diag.aspx and looking at the Latency Test and Bandwidth Test.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Those numbers all look good - we're talking milliseconds, and 390 KB/sec for the bandwidth test...

Comment: Then I would definitely look at those workflows. I was adding contacts at an average of 282ms and you are over an order of magnitude greater at 3290ms. If you deactivate all the workflows, what do you get when running that performance test?

Comment: Hi Nick - quick one for you. Do workflows complete in the scope of inserting data i.e. using the CRM SDK, if you insert data, does the Workflow complete before the call to the Api is completed? If so, it's a shame in a way that it doesnt complete the API call and then run the workflow...

Comment: It depends, a real-time/synchronous workflow does complete before the API call completed. An asynchronous workflow will run AFTER the API call is completed successfully. See: http://blog.clickdimensions.com/2013/12/using-real-time-synchronous-workflows-in-dynamics-crm-2013.html